# python: write a dataframe groupby to a file

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a file with the following that I am reading with python

```
Item Master Primary Spec/Common Information/Contract Number||Contract Master Primary Spec/cage code
8AND3||SP47W117D0015
8AND3||SP47W117D0015
8AND3||SP47W117D0015
8AND3||SP47W117D0015
8AND3||SP47W117D0015
8C1C2||N6247820D2401
8C1C2||N6247820D2401
8C1C2||N6247820D2401
```

I am trying to get a count of the number of contracts. The below code seems to work when I print it (although the header columns are reversed for some reason), but not when I try to output it to a file.

```
import pandas as pd

fname="mdm.export.item.master.delta.1335.20220120011500_125_125.csv"
fdir="./data/"
df = pd.read_csv(fdir+fname, sep='\|\|', keep_default_na=False, engine='python')

uniqContract=df.groupby(['Item Master Primary Spec/Common Information/Contract Number']).count()
print(uniqContract)

file = open("testfile.txt","w") 
for items in uniqContract:
    file.writelines(items+'\n')
file.close()
```

This is the print output

```
(base) PS D:\02-MyLocalFiles> python .\helloworld.py
Contract Master Primary Spec/cage code Item Master Primary Spec/Common Information/Con...
8AND3                                                                                    5
8C1C2                                                                                    3
(base) PS D:\02-MyLocalFiles\python\backlog_report>
```

But this is the output to the file

```
Contract Master Primary Spec/cage code
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you want the contents of the file to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
uniqContract=df.groupby(['Item Master Primary Spec/Common Information/Contract Number']).count().reset_index()
uniqContract.to_csv('testfile.txt', delimiter='\t')
```

You can call `.reset_index()` on your groupby count aggregation, then write that to a (text) csv file directly.  You can specify the delimiter (this is tabs).

Answer (score 0):

`uniqContract` is a dataframe, and when you loop over a dataframe, it loops over the dataframes columns. `uniqContract` looks like this:

```
                                                    Contract Master Primary Spec/cage code
Item Master Primary Spec/Common Information/Con...                                        
8AND3                                                                                    5
8C1C2                                                                                    3
```

...which has only one column, so that's why you get `Contract Master Primary Spec/cage code` in your file.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using pandas.dataFrame `read_csv`

Use pandas.dataFrame `to_csv` with no index column so that you don't get an extra id for every row.

```
uniqContract.to_csv("testfile.csv", index=False)
```

A link to the documentation for https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html